# Python, how do i add two values together from same column numpy and iterate an add function on that specific column numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, math

I'm working on some python binance data, and have ran into a problem. I want to do simple math on a single column and iterate math on that same column.
The data I'm working with is volume from a binance feed.

This is my code:

```py
candles = client.get_historical_klines("BTCUSDT", Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR, "1 day ago UTC")
candle_dataframe = df(candles)
candle_dataframe_date = candle_dataframe[0]

date_init = []

for time in candle_dataframe_date.unique():
    readable = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time/1000))
    date_init.append(readable)

candle_dataframe.pop(0)
candle_dataframe.pop(11)

dataframe_final_date = df(date_init)
dataframe_final_date.columns = ['date']

final_dataframe = candle_dataframe.join(dataframe_final_date)
final_dataframe.set_index('date', inplace=True)
final_dataframe.columns = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'close_time', 'asset_volume', 'trade_number', 'taker_buy_base', 'taker_buy_quote']

list_volume = final_dataframe.iloc[:, [4]]
np_array = list_volume.to_numpy()

arr = np_array.astype('float64')
np.transpose(arr)
#print(np.transpose(arr))

#example 1
b = np_array[::2]
a = np_array[1::2]

print(np.add(a, b))

#example two
#for i, values, values1 in np_array:
#    values[0] += 1
#    if i == values[1]:
#        np.multiply(values, values1)
#result = np.add(a + b)
```

Example two kind of shows what I'm trying to do, I hope.
But is there a way to control, the id iteration so that I get the last volume and the next from there and add those together, then add the next two values and so on?

It seems impossible to create simple math on single column ids, or is there a way through it.

I just think it would be silly to have to copy the column and work with redundant data, to actually perform the math.

Comment: ignore backticks sorry about that.

Comment: You might want to read about numpy's broadcasting and vectorization. E.g. [this article](https://unidata.github.io/python-training/workshop/NumPy/numpy-broadcasting-and-vectorization/).  In any case, you should avoid `for` loops.  A `for` loop with an `if` often can be emulated by `np.where`.  Note that `a * b` when `a` and `b` are numpy arrays, will result in an element wise multiplication.  `np.multiply` will be called "behind the scene", so it doesn't need to be called explicitly.

Comment: I will check out the article, but there wierd thing is even if i take two seperate id cells, and use the add() function, it gives me this result, which is not a plus/addition of the two cells. ['3145.110826001952.71192400']

Comment: based on that output, the ids are strings, so plus/add gets overloaded as string concatenation

Comment: The answer to my question was in the comment posting an article and is this function.

        d = np.zeros(arr.size - 1)
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        d[i] = arr[i + 1] + arr[i]

Thank you so much.

Mathias

Answer (score 2):

Why loop? Shouldn't this work?

```
arr = np.random.rand(10)
d = arr[:-1] + arr[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was in the comment posting an article and is this function.

```
d = np.zeros(arr.size - 1)
for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
    d[i] = arr[i + 1] + arr[i]
```

Thank you so much.

Mathias